# Elastic Search: Tire: Data import too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I want to index close to 900,000 documents but it is taking quite long. I have defined a mapping which contains indexes on the lines of:

```
indexes :residencies_with_year,     type: 'string',     :as => 'residencies_obj.map{|r| ExpertProfile.residency_with_year_to_s(r)}'
```

Thus I believe there are quite a few database queries as I'm indexing the model. I'm using the default configuration: number of nodes =1, number of shards=5, and number of replicas=1. 
Each batch of 1000 documents is taking about 15 minutes.

How can I speed it up?

Here's the rake command i'm using

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Expert' FORCE=true
```

Comment: If the content is large the import takes time. Is it possible for you to reduce the data to be indexed in elasticsearch. In that case you can gain some time or else you can't. But, taking 15min for 1000 docs is way too much time. Are you running this in your local machine?

Comment: Tire import uses only select queries.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can try parallel import with time ranges. **Don't use force option in this case**

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Expert.scoped(:conditions => [created_at<? and created_at>?', Time.now.utc, Time1])'
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Expert.scoped(:conditions => [created_at<? and created_at>?', Time1, Time2])'
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Expert.scoped(:conditions => [created_at<? and created_at>?', Time2, Time3])'
```

This might speed up **total time** of the import process.